# Powered USB3 Hub vs USB3 Y Power Cable

Tags: power-supply, usb-power, hard-drive, usb-hub

I have an issue that means I have to use a powered USB hub for the HDD that is attached to my RPI4 (long story). The hub just broke.

My budget doesn't allow for a decent powered USB3 hub BUT does allow for a decent USB3 Y Power Cable.

Rookie question, but would this work? I just want the HDD to have its own power supply.

Further question: If it would work, can I just plug both Y ends of the power cable into the Pi to get more power for the HDD?

Cheers!

Comment: I had an external DVD Drive with one of those Y-cables, and there is not a single computer that it worked with - either a single port provided enough power, or even two ports didn't provide enough power.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> This answer is incorrect.
> Depending on model & OS USB can supply 1.2A.
> [Typical Power Requirements](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#typical-power-requirements)

I doubt it would work, according to this page: [USB - port power limits](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/usb/README.md#powerlimits) the Raspberry Pi USB ports are designed to handle 100mA each so the advice is to always use an external hub with its own power supply for a USB hard drive (and other "high-power" devices).

Comment: This looks like the answer I didn't want to hear but is almost definitely correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think that at the very least you should consider using a separate power adapter on the usb-power connector end of the cable.
As otherwise, plugging both usb ends to the Pi4/Pi400 ports won't give any more power to the HDD.

P.s.
For awareness I posted a similar question specifically regarding pros/cons of powering the HDD this way that might interest you

[Y-Cable and power adapter to power external HDD](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/142697/y-cable-to-power-usb3-hdd-on-pi400)